# Using textual references in itext

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to use a textual reference with itext and I have no clue on how to do it. Something like this number four in the image below.

[image]

I'm using the following code to generate the Ref. cell:

```
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Ref.", tableHeaderFont));
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.setBackgroundColor(cellBackgroundColor);
            cell.setRowspan(1);
            documentsAcceptedTable.addCell(cell);
```

How can I place the number to make a reference?

Comment: If you mean you need a superscript as mentioned in above image, please refer to http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/superscript-subscript.html

Comment: Also: this is easier to achieve in iText 7 (so if you are new to iText, don't start with iText 5, start with iText 7 instead).

Comment: @Sid thanks a lot. If you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: As it is a link based answer, it won't be acceptable. I urge you to post a detailed answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Sid for the [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/superscript-subscript.html) he gave me.

I've solved my problem with some minor changes to my previous code, using Paragraph instead of Phrase:

```
            paragraph =new Paragraph("Ref.",
                                     tableHeaderFont);
            chunk = new Chunk("4", superScriptFont); //in here I've added the number 4
            chunk.setTextRise(3f); //and then applied a textRise
            paragraph.add(chunk);

            cell = new PdfPCell(paragraph);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.setBackgroundColor(cellBackgroundColor);
            documentsAcceptedTable.addCell(cell);
```